# can we load types from the appdomain?

Tags: .net, spring, dependency-injection, appdomain

My application does not have a configuration. Will I be able to still use the spring framework?

I'm also looking to load assemblies into my appdomain on the fly...now how do I use types loaded in that assembly using spring.net

Comment: What do you mean by _application does not have a configuration_? Depending on your needs, some Spring modules require configuration.

Comment: Application is supposed to run in the context of a SSIS package inside of a script component (Data Flow Task)...